# How to fetch values from more than one table from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

How to fetch rows from various table and performing sum operation?

For Example
**Table1:** tree

```
-------------------
id        name     
-------------------
1         tree1    
-------------------
2         tree2    
-------------------
3         tree3    
-------------------
4         tree4    
-------------------
```

**Table2:** leaf

```
--------------------------------
tree_id        name        value
--------------------------------
1              test1          5
--------------------------------
1              test2          3   
--------------------------------
2              test3          7
--------------------------------
4              test4          9
--------------------------------
```

Desired Output:

```
select tree.id,tree.name,sum(leaf.value) as total from tree,leaf where leaf.tree_id=tree.id

Array([0] => Array([id]=>1, [name]=>tree1, [total]=>8),
[1] => Array([id]=>2, [name]=>tree2, [total]=>7)
[2] => Array([id]=>3, [name]=>tree3, [total]=>0)
[3] => Array([id]=>4, [name]=>tree4, [total]=>9))
```

Comment: Take a look at JOIN, INNER JOIN, OUTER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and CROSS JOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT tree.id, tree.name, sum(leaf.value) as total
FROM tree
LEFT JOIN leaf
  ON leaf.tree_id = tree.id
GROUP BY tree.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tree.id, tree.name, sum(leaf.value) as total
FROM tree
left  join leaf
  ON leaf.tree_id = tree.id group by tree.id
```